# What is the mechanics for a Matrix Search action?

Tags: actions, shadowrun-sr5, sr5-matrix

Matrix Search is a Special Action. To look for a file inside a host takes up to 1 min. This brings me some questions:

1. What does a Special Action means in terms of Action Phases? Can I make a Simple Action and start a Matrix Search in my Action Phase (like a Simple Action does) or does a Matrix Search use all the Action Phase (like a Complex Action)?
2. Can I perform other actions during the Matrix Search? If so, there will be modifiers?

Answer (score 1):

The Matrix Search can be correlated to doing a Google search today for information on a topic. For example, googling information about what a Matrix Search is, is itself a Matrix Search. Because of this you would not be using this during your Action Phases and it will need your full attention to track down the information.

If you are in a host already and making use of Action Phases, most likely you are using Matrix Perception which is a Complex Action to look through the host to find what you need. You may need multiple depending on the test difficulty and what you exactly want to do. It even has the same Computer + Intuition as a Matrix Search, but a better fit to what is going on during an encounter.